# Python reduce on len() function

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have

```
>>> reduce( (lambda x,y: x + y), [1,2,3])

6
```

And

```
>>> reduce( (lambda x,y: x + y), ['cat','dog','hat'])

'catdoghat'
```

Then, I'd like to get the sum of all string elements in the list:

```
>>> reduce( (lambda x,y: len(x) + len(y)), ['cat','dog','hat'])
```

It produces an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, map(len, ['cat','dog','hat']))`

Answer (score 4):

Think about your reduce operation:

```
(len((len('cat') + len('dog')))+ len('hat'))
```

You will end up calling `len` on an `int`. You probably want:

```
sum(map(len, ['cat','dog','hat']))
```

And stop re-inventing the wheel and using `reduce` for `sum`.

Note also, using `sum` (which is equivalent to `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, ...)` is going to have *terrible* performance for strings, i.e. O(n^2). Instead, use `''.join(sequence_of_strings)`

Indeed, the interpreter will yell at you if you even try!

```
>>> sum(['a','b','c'], '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann O! It's great that it doesn't let you do that. You can still, unfortunately, sum on `list` objects, so `sum([[1],[2],[3]], [])`

Comment: Well, ok, not really all the time. But when I know it's fast enough and am too lazy to type something efficient.

Comment: @StefanPochmann and a baby ... functional programming mascot dies when you do `reduce(list.__iadd__, [[1],[2],[3]])`

Comment: @StefanPochmann yep, relying on the handy fact that `reduce` is a fold-l operation, otherwise, I think it would be just as inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

reduce is a process in which you iteratively go over all the items and apply an operation, let's try to do it with your example:

```
reduce( (lambda x,y: len(x) + len(y)), ['cat','dog','hat'])
```

so first `x` is 'cat' and `y` is 'dog' and the output is 6, now we'll have `x` as 6 and `y` as 'hat' and we'll fail on `len(6)`

What you want to do instead is sum the lengths of the strings, you can use `map` for that because unlike `reduce` map applies a function on all the items (which is exactly what you want - to apply `len` to each and every item) and sum will take care of the addition:

```
sum(map(len, ['cat','dog','hat']))
```